# Restoring FramelessWindow position after maximized

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm writing some functions to `move`, `maximize`, and `restore` a frameless window built using `Qt`.

When the window gets maximized by double clicking on it, and the user tries to drag it, I'm not figuring out how to properly return it to her previous position.

### Example:

```cpp
class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow() {};

    QWidget *titlebar_widget;

    bool mMoving;
    bool maximized;

    QPoint mLastMousePosition;
    QPoint mLastMousePositionBeforeMaximize;

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) 
    {
        if (!titlebar_widget->underMouse())
            return;

        if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) 
        {
            mMoving = true;
            mLastMousePosition = event->pos();
        }
    }

    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
    {
        if (!titlebar_widget->underMouse())
            return;

        if ((maximized) && (event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::LeftButton) && mMoving))
        {
            slot_restored();
            maximized = false;
            mLastMousePosition = mLastMousePositionBeforeMaximize;
            return;
        }

        if (event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::LeftButton) && mMoving)
            this->move(this->pos() + (event->pos() - mLastMousePosition));
    }

    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event) 
    {
        if (!titlebar_widget->underMouse())
            return;

        if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
            mMoving = false;
    }

    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
    {
        Q_UNUSED(event);

        if (!titlebar_widget->underMouse())
            return;

        if (event->button() != Qt::LeftButton)
            return;

        maximized = !maximized;
        if (maximized)
        {
            mLastMousePositionBeforeMaximize = event->pos();
            slot_maximized();
        }
        else
            slot_restored();
    }

    void slot_minimized() { setWindowState(Qt::WindowMinimized); }
    void slot_restored() { setWindowState(Qt::WindowNoState); }
    void slot_maximized() { setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized); }

private:
    Ui::MainWindowClass ui;
};
```

---

```cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    ui.centralWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 155);");
    
    titlebar_widget = ui.centralWidget;
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
}
```

To be more precise my question lies here:

```cpp
        // The window is maximized, user has leftbutton down, and is 
        // trying to move it.
        if ((maximized) && (event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::LeftButton) && mMoving))
        {
            slot_restored();
            maximized = false;
            mLastMousePosition = mLastMousePositionBeforeMaximize;
        }
```

Then the window is restored to her previous pos/size `slot_restored();`
and the following code moves the window around:

```cpp
        if (event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::LeftButton) && mMoving)
            this->move(this->pos() + (event->pos() - mLastMousePosition));
```

But at this point I'm getting a weird movement, its moving the window to a different position than it was before:

[image]

In the gif isn't much noticeable because of the fps, but the window is jumping around.

How to properly calculate her position when it gets restored by dragging?

Comment: `this->move(this->pos() + (event->pos() - mLastMousePosition)``- you are using the mouse co-ordinates, not the windows co-ordinates. Since the mouse can click anywhere on the title bar, you're not saving the window origin, but restoring it using the moouse co-ordinates

Comment: @Noscere i still didnt get it

Comment: I didn't understand your problem.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R the problem is when the gui is maximized and i try to move it by click/drag, at this moment the gui jumps to a wrong position

Comment: @Raja you shouldn't drag it when maximizing it ,please see my github code I have checked there if maximized was true I didn't allow drag happens.

Answer (score 1):

why do you define UI object like this `Ui::MainWindowClass ui;`?

The only thing that I changed in your code was this and it works well for me I create the default widget mainWindow and this is:

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMouseEvent>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui
{
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    ~MainWindow();


    QWidget *titlebar_widget;
    bool     mMoving;
    bool     maximized;
    QPoint   mLastMousePosition;
    QPoint   mLastMousePositionBeforeMaximize;

    void  mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
        if (!titlebar_widget->underMouse())
        {
            return;
        }

        if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
        {
            mMoving            = true;
            mLastMousePosition = event->pos();
        }
    }

    void  mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

    void  mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

    void  mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

    void  slot_minimized();

    void  slot_restored();

    void  slot_maximized();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->centralwidget->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 155);");

    titlebar_widget = ui->centralwidget;
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void  MainWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (!titlebar_widget->underMouse())
    {
        return;
    }

    if ((maximized) && (event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::LeftButton) && mMoving))
    {
        slot_restored();
        maximized          = false;
        mLastMousePosition = mLastMousePositionBeforeMaximize;

        return;
    }

    if (event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::LeftButton) && mMoving)
    {
        this->move(this->pos() + (event->pos() - mLastMousePosition));
    }
}

void  MainWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (!titlebar_widget->underMouse())
    {
        return;
    }

    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        mMoving = false;
    }
}

void  MainWindow::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);

    if (!titlebar_widget->underMouse())
    {
        return;
    }

    if (event->button() != Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        return;
    }

    maximized = !maximized;

    if (maximized)
    {
        mLastMousePositionBeforeMaximize = event->pos();
        slot_maximized();
    }
    else
    {
        slot_restored();
    }
}

void  MainWindow::slot_minimized()
{
    setWindowState(Qt::WindowMinimized);
}

void  MainWindow::slot_restored()
{
    setWindowState(Qt::WindowNoState);
}

void  MainWindow::slot_maximized()
{
    setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
}
```

**This is my result:**

[image]

**But This is the better option for what you are doing:**

Please clone the repo from GitHub(it has more changes):

https://github.com/parisa-hr/Draggable-and-Movable-Frameless-Window

**This is the result:**

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for trying it, in your first gif you are double-clicking the GUI or you are moving it while it's already maximized? When I maximize the GUI and then try to move it, it restores and moves to a wrong position.

Comment: In your second gif example the GUI goes fullscreen that's not what I'm aiming for, my goal is just to maximize.

Comment: @Raja please clone and test it , the idea of moving it has some differences, and also you shouldn't allow dragging happens when maximized was happens.

Comment: @Raja did you test it? If you still have problem create one github repo we can work on it together.

Comment: Blocking the GUI from being dragged when maximized is not a solution, I think you are confusing a window maximized and a window on full screen. Maximize your browser and drag it, is it blocked?

Comment: @Raja what is your OS and QT version?

Comment: I checked [my code](https://github.com/parisa-hr/Draggable-and-Movable-Frameless-Window)I dont have Blocking or other problems. My OS is ubuntu 20.04 and I test it in Qt 6.2.3 and Qt 5.15

Comment: Win10 Qt 6.4, https://github.com/parisa-hr/Draggable-and-Movable-Frameless-Window/blob/a32a1159a7bec8e3406a5d3e3b18ed05eea35734/mainwindow.cpp#L38 try commenting this line `if (!maximized)`, the problem is not blocking is the gui is moved to a wrong position when maximized/restore-drag

Comment: It is strange
I have to find a Windows system and check it, I will tell the result.

Comment: @Raja Do you want to have something like a browser window? because when we want to drag the browser window it's not maximized and also we cant drag it from middel  of the window, we press the top side.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the name of your co-ordinate variable

```cpp
    mLastMousePosition
```

which you use to restore the window after it is no longer maximised:

```cpp
        // The window is maximized, user has leftbutton down, and is 
        // trying to move it.
        if ((maximized) && (event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::LeftButton) && mMoving))
        {
            slot_restored();
            maximized = false;
            mLastMousePosition = mLastMousePositionBeforeMaximize;
        }
```

Are you are using the mouse pointer position to put the window back onto the screen? If so, you're using the wrong data. (Although looking at the slot_restored() function, you're not actually providing any co-ordinates?)

To explain what I meant in my comment, each window has its own position, for example if the window is in the very top left corner, then its co-ordinates will be 0,0 - irrelevant of where the mouse pointer is. If you then retored the window to the mLastMousePosition, this could be anywhere along the title bar of the window (even as far as close to the top right corner, restoring your window so that it is almost off the screen).

You might be saving the mouse position for other purposes? It's not clear from your code snippet - but you probably want to be saving the window position before it gets maximised, so that you can restore it again later ...

This might be of great help for you:

[Save Window Widget Geometry](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#saveGeometry) and [Restore QWidget Gemoetry](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#restoreGeometry)

Comment: The problem is not geometry, even with the api you linked, it still 'jumps'